# How to manipulate the DOM with Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onsen-ui

I'm a total newbie to Onsen UI and I managed to make my first little app (static that is) with a few pages, popovers, lists, etc.

But when I try to add dynamic stuff in there, it does not want to cooperate.

When I click my side menu, it calls menu.setMainPage and in the callback I want to modify the content of the list (lets say iterate a JSON request and add a ons-list-item for each of them). However, they do not look styled with Onsen UI icing.

I guess it's because the menu.setMainPage has already parsed the ons-page and showed it in the browser.

Is there a way to do a load page, update the dom, and then pass it to be displayed?

I have a simila problem with an popover that contains a list. I want to add items in that list, but my jQuery append never work. Same reason I suppose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're not running `ons.compile()` on the dynamic elements. The custom elements must be compiled after they've been added to the DOM to get the correct style and behavior.

I made a short example to illustrate it:

```
ons.bootstrap();

var addItem = function() {
  var $myList = $("#my-list"),
      $item = $("<ons-list-item>").text(Math.random());

  $myList.append($item[0]);
  ons.compile($item[0]);
};
```

If you attach the `addItem` function to a click handler you can add items dynamically to an `<ons-list>`.

This is a running example on codepen:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/gbxNEg

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing! Thank you very much!